# Ajax form won't post form data via php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

First, I'm not a web developer. But I have come upon this problem with a friend trying to develop a website. He has a button html tag that looks like:

```
<form id="frm">

    <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text" placeholder="Enter Text Here "></textarea>

</form>



<div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="btndiv"> 
<button type="button" id="btnSend" class="btn btn-primary mr-auto">Send</button>
</div>
```

And a javascript file which uses ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSend").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: './request.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {message: $("#message-text").val()},
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#resp').prepend('<img id="theImg" src="./success/qr.png" />')
                       $('#frm').hide();
                       $('#btndiv').hide();
                       
                
                }
              
            });
        });
    });
```

And a request.php file:

```
<?php
              
if(isset($_POST['message-text']))
{
$data=$_POST['message-text'];
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'data.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

His goal is to get the server to write the form contents to a data.txt file in the root directory of the server. He has it served locally and actually the "success" function will work where the image will pop up. But ajax never calls the POST function in response. I tried to mess around with it myself, but I'm unfamiliar with web deveopment. Anyone know what could be wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a browser problem (where the JS does not work as expected), or a server problem (where PHP does not work as expected)?

Comment: A piece of advice: have the PHP script return some values which you can then check in the success handler. You are currently assuming everything is going okay (you're not checking `response` in any way). You could send something like a simple JSON with `"success": true` or `"success": false`, depending on whether the operation was completed or not.

Comment: I can get it to prepend the png which must mean it is successful, but it's not grabbing the form data for some reason. So I guess the php is working. It has something to do with not being able to post the form data. I changed php to use "message" rather than "message-text" but still not writing to the file.

Answer (score 1):

It should be.

```
<?php
              
if(isset($_POST['message']))
{
$data=$_POST['message'];
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'data.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

The reason why is that you are passing object in your javaScript file which is "message".

```
data: {message: $("#message-text").val()},
```

Comment: Hmm i tried this as well. Still not saving to data.txt :( I checked the permisisons on the file and just added all, so not a permissions issue. Does this have anything to do with the site being hosted locally in apache? I'm a server monkey, so I can load services, but I have no clue when it comes to trying to connect html to js to php.

Comment: Hi @tonton there might be a problem with permission related in your server.